# Resize BitVec in z3 [Python]

Tags: python-3.x, z3, z3py

I need to symbolize an unknown length byte string in z3. I see two options: symbolize each byte necessary, then concat bytes when constraints need to be applied, or symbolize one long bytestring, extracting portions when constraints need to be applied.

One long bytestring seems more convenient, but it would need to be resized when a larger amount of data is needed. Does z3 have a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on what you precisely mean by *Resize*.

If you mean you want to *change* the size of an existing bit-vector variable later on to be something else; then the answer is "no." Once you declare a variable with a certain bitvector size (or any type for that matter), you cannot change it later on.

However, if you mean whether you can create a new variable from the old; then yes.

To extend: You can either sign-extend or zero-extend depending on your need to account for 2's complement numbers or unsigned bitvectors to any new larger size. (Use `Concat` to extend with either 0's or the sign bit of the original. See here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a4dfadd3cb36aaa827c9202a949a506a4)

To shrink, you can use `Extract`: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a40e9429ef16134a6d9914ecdc2182e8c, by extracting an arbitrary segment as you need.

Note that in all cases, the new size has to be concretely known. There's some discussion in the following thread regarding why this is the case: [Z3 BitVec extraction using symbolic high and low](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51369215/z3-bitvec-extraction-using-symbolic-high-and-low/51370305#51370305) The bottom line is that SMTLib Bitvector logic is about fixed-size bitvectors, and thus the sizes have to be concretely known (nothing can be symbolic about the sizes of bitvectors) at compile time.

But, to emphasize the original point, extending or shrinking a bitvector merely creates a new one that has the same value as the old (symbolic or otherwise), assuming that value fits in the new representation. (Otherwise you'll get a modulo truncation.) But more importantly, the original variable and all the expressions that depend on do *not* get impacted by this change; you're merely creating a new bitvector. In that sense, resizing an existing bitvector variable is just not possible in the SMT-land.